# Make Chrome extension refresh already open page instead of opening new one

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The extension sends a notification when a message is received.

```
var notification = new Notification('New message', {
    icon: icon,
    body: dabody,
});
```

It also opens a page displaying the messages when clicked.

```
notification.onclick = function () {
    window.open(link);
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://website/messages/", selected: false, pinned: true}, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            code: 'window.close();',
            runAt: 'document_idle'
        });
    });
    notification.close();
}
```

Is there a way I can have the `/messages` page refresh if it's already open instead of opening a new page?

Comment: See [`tabs.update()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update).

Answer (score 0):

When your event is fired you can try to find the tab via `chrome.tabs.query` and reload it, or create a new one in otherwise.

Something like this:

```
notification.onclick = function () {
    chrome.tabs.query({url:"https://website/messages/"}, function(tabs) {
        if(tabs.length) { 
            chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[0].tabId); 
        }
        else {
            // create new tab
        }
    });
};
```